# Insert spaces between large numbers in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want VBA code which can add spacing in large numbers, like i have numbers 8789798987978979879 and i want result like 8789 7989 8797 8979 79.

or any VBA code which converts into parts.

thanks

Comment: Please take a moment to read the guidelines in the [help] for asking questions on Stack Overflow. You're expetect to *show effort* - not expect the people who help here to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA to do this.  It can be done with a very basic wildcard search and replace.

In the search and replace dialog make sure that the Wildcard checkbox is ticked.

In the 'find what' field enter

'([0-9]{4,4})([0-9])'  without the ''

In the 'replace with' field enter
'\1 \2' again without the ''

Keep pressing 'replace all' until you get zero replacements.

What is happening?

[0-9] means find any single character in the range 0-9.  The character range has to be in Ascii order.

{,} means find a number of the characters immediately preceding the {} so

[0-9]{4,4} means find at least and not more than 4 characters in the range [0-9]

()  means remember what you found.

in the replace box \1 says use the first 'find what' remembered (\2 the second 'find what' etc)

so

([0-9]{4,4})([0-9]) applied to 1234567890

will find and remember the 1234 as \1 and 5 as \2

the 'replace with' of \1 \2 will give us

1234 56789

BUT because 6789 is not followed by a number it won't be found which is why you need to repeat the replace all.

You can read more about wildcard searches here

https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

The VBA equivalent is to run a find/replace in a loop until the find term is no longer found.

```
Sub test()

    splitBigNumbers 3

End Sub

Public Sub splitBigNumbers(Optional splitAt As Long = 4)

    replaceText_ReplaceAllWithWildcardOption ActiveDocument, Replace("([0-9]{###,###})([0-9])", "###", CStr(splitAt)), "\1 \2", True

End Sub


Sub replaceText_ReplaceAllWithWildcardOption(this_document As Word.Document, findText As String, replaceText As String, Optional useWildcard = False)

Dim my_continue                                     As Boolean
    Do
        With this_document.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Format = False
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Text = findText
            .Replacement.Text = replaceText
            .Forward = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = useWildcard
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            my_continue = .Found

        End With

    Loop While my_continue

End Sub
```